# comparison operator false

Tags: javascript

```
var a = '1000';
var b = '200';         

console.log(a > b);=> false
```

why?

Comment: Because you are comparing strings. Remove the single quotes.

Comment: Because you compare strings, not int's. Do `console.log(parseInt(a) > parseInt(b))`

Comment: If the input is in string, try converting them into integer using parseInt and then do the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are **comparing strings, not numbers**.

It compares each character in the same position from the left. So '1' is lower than '2' in character set, it stops comparing and returns `false`.

```js
console.log('1000' > '200')
// false
console.log(1000 > 200)
// true
```

Comment: nó có so sánh độ dài của chuỗi không ??

Comment: Could you write it in English again?

Comment: thank you . I was understand .

Comment: does it compare the length of the string ?? i think it compases its  string length

Comment: It does not. `'1000'.length > '200'.length` is comparing the length of the strings.